# GPU runs out of memory on AzureML Studio when uing YOLOv8

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, yolov8

I am using Notebooks on Azure AI Machine Learning Studio to train a classification model using Yolov8 (pip install ultralytics).

On training, I get an error that suggests my compute is out of memory:

[image]

**My set-up**

Code: (running in a `ipynb` notebook on Azure ML studio):

```
import os
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO('yolov8n-cls.pt')  

# Train the model: https://docs.ultralytics.com/usage/cfg/
results = model.train(
    name='my_classification_run',
    task='classify',
    data='data', 
    batch=16,
    epochs=1,
    imgsz=64,
    device=0,
    cache=True,
    val=True
    )
```

Dataset: 64x64 colour .jpg files as follows:

- Train: 2,385 files; ~9.35MB
- Valid: 299 files; ~1.16MB

Compute:

1. Standard_NV12s_v3 (12 cores, 112 GB RAM, 336 GB disk)
2. GPU - 1 x NVIDIA Tesla M60 processing unit.

**Things I've tried:**

1. Check **CUDA is available**. Yes it is.
2. Check if **NVIDIA driver installed**. I ran nvidia-smi at CMD line
   and confirmed it.
3. Check if any **GPU processes running and kill them**. Checked.
   Non-running.
4. Try **different batch sizes** as well as **autobatch**. Tried 8, 16, 32 and autobatch.
5. Use **nano** model. Yes, downloaded that as pretrained model.

In total my images are ~10 MB. My GPU has 112 GM RAM. I am not expert, but I assume that is sufficient memory?

Finally, in terms of the logs, the final line printed before the memory issue is flagged is the following:

> YOLOv8n-cls summary: 99 layers, 1443412 parameters, 1443412 gradients, 3.4 GFLOPs
> Transferred 156/158 items from pretrained weights

I'd be grateful if anybody has any pointers on how to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I did some reading and figured out it was the CPU that was the bottlneck. I switched my compute on Azure to a compute optimised CPU and this enabled me to train my model.

Comment: which one is that compute?

Comment: I used this one (as listed on my computer options for CPU) ~~> Intel Xeon Platinum 8272CL 2.60GHz